# Convert [IO Int] to IO [Int] in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

I have this code that fits my need:

```
f :: [IO Int] -> IO [Int]
f [] = return []
f (x:xs) = do 
  a <- x
  as <- f xs
  return (a:as)
```

But I thougth there would be a predefined way (msum ?)

But I can't see how.

Any help would be welcome. Thx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it's available in the standard library under the name [`sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3asequence). It has a more general type than your `f`: `Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`, since it works for any `Monad`, not just `IO`.

You could find it yourself by searching for type [`[IO a] -> IO [a]`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=%5bIO+a%5d+-%3E+IO+%5ba%5d&format=sherlock) on [**Hoogle**](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle).